# How do I add 'setPreserveViewport' option to KmlLayer in Java?

Tags: java, kml

I'm relatively new, so there might be a very simple answer to this question, but how do I add the 'setPreserveViewport' option to KmlLayer in Java? I have found one solution, but that doesn’t work to well with showing multiple KML layers.

So what I have now is:

```
    final KmlLayer KMLmap1 = KmlLayer.create("https://earthbuilder.googleusercontent.com/04956359305736194955-05414812628978701557-4/2/kml/link.kml");
    final KmlLayer KMLmap2 = KmlLayer.create("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20845226/alledanmarks5regioner.kml");



    class KMLButtonPanel extends FlowPanel {
    public KMLButtonPanel() {
            Button KML1Btn = new Button("KML 1", new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                  kmlUnload(KMLmap2);

                  kmlLoad(KMLmap1);

              }

            });

            Button KML2Btn = new Button("KML 2", new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                  kmlUnload(KMLmap1);

                  kmlLoad(KMLmap2);


              }

            });
    }

public void onModuleLoad() {


    private void kmlLoad(KmlLayer layer) {
                layers = layer;
                layers.setMap(map);

        }

      private void kmlUnload(KmlLayer layer) {
                layers = layer;
                layers.setMap(null);
        }
    }
```

I also have a lot of other code, so I have just copied the lines out that are relevant. Now the thing I want to do, is somehow add the setPreserveViewport(true) option – and that’s where I’m at! How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the solution was quite simple:

```
  private KmlLayer layers;

  private String KMLmap1 = "https://earthbuilder.googleusercontent.com/04956359305736194955-05414812628978701557-4/2/kml/link.kml";
  private String KMLmap2 = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20845226/alledanmarks5regioner.kml";
```

and then when I run kmlLoad(KMLmap1); or kmlLoad(KMLmap2); I get:

```
private void kmlLoad(String string) {

        if (layers != null) {
            kmlUnload();
        }

        KmlLayerOptions layerOpts = KmlLayerOptions.create();
        layerOpts.setPreserveViewport(true);
        KmlLayer newlayers = KmlLayer.create(
                string,
                layerOpts
            );
        layers = newlayers;
        newlayers.setMap(map);

  }

  private void kmlUnload() {
        layers.setMap(null);
    }
```